# Tengo problemas al pasar variables por AJAX ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Estoy tratando de pasar 7 variables por ajax. Las capturo mediante un .val y luego procedo hacer el envío mediante ajax. Recibo los valores y los printeo (print_r()) pero en con sola me sale undefined.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var a = '';

        $("#tabla").change(function(){


            a = $("#tabla").val();

            if (a == 'personigrama') {

                    $("#personigrama").css("display","block");
                    $("#materiales").css("display","none");
                    $("#codconsumo").css("display","none");

            } 

            if (a == 'materiales') {
                //alert("Es materiales");
                    $("#materiales").css("display","block");
                    $("#personigrama").css("display","none");
                    $("#codconsumo").css("display","none");

            }

            if (a == 'codconsumo'){
                //alert("Es código de consumo");
                    $("#codconsumo").css("display","block");
                    $("#materiales").css("display","none");
                    $("#personigrama").css("display","none");
            }
        });

        $("#codmaterial").keypress(function(){

            var buscar = $("#codmaterial").val();

                $("#codmaterial").autocomplete({

                    source: "../perfiles/buscar_tablas.php?buscar=" + buscar + '&select' + a,
                         minLength: 2,

                    select: function(event, ui) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                        $('#codmaterial').val(ui.item.COD_MATERIAL); 
                        $('#descripcion').val(ui.item.DESCRIPCION);
                        $('#unymed').val(ui.item.UNIMED); 
                        $('#serializado').val(ui.item.SERIALIZADO);
                        $('#tipmat').val(ui.item.TIPO_MATERIAL); 
                        $('#valor').val(ui.item.VALOR);
                        $('#pertenencia').val(ui.item.PERTENENCIA);
                    }

                });
        });

$("#actualizar").on("click", function(){

            var codmaterial = $("#codmaterial").val();
            var descripcionmaterial = $("#descripcion").val();
            var unidadymedida  = $("#unymed").val();
            var serializado  = $("#serializado").val();
            var tipomaterial  = $("#tipmat").val();
            var valor  = $("#valor").val();
            var pertenencia  = $("#pertenencia").val();

            //console.log("Código material: " + codmaterial + ", Descripcion: " + descripcionmaterial + ", Unidad y medida: " + unidadymedida + ", Serialiado: " + serializado + ", Tipo material: " + tipomaterial + ", Valor: " + valor + ", Pertenencia: " + pertenencia);

var save=$.ajax({

type:'POST',
url: '../perfiles/acciones_tablas.php',
data: 'codmaterial'+codmaterial+'&descripcion'+descripcionmaterial+'&unymed'+unidadymedida+'&serializado'+serializado+'&tipmat'+tipomaterial+'&valor'+valor+'&pertenencia'+pertenencia,
async: false,
dataType: 'HTML',
success: function () {
    console.log('Enviada la información exitosamente!');
} 

}).reponseText;

console.log(save);
});
```

El flujo se va por success. Pero al momento de que devuelva el responseText 
   me bota en cosola el undefined.

Agradecería bastante de su tiempo y ayuda.

Comment: Realmente no se por qué quieres el responseText. Tu puedes tener el parametro success con un parametro que es la respuesta que recibes del php, de esta manera: `success: function(respuesta){console.log('La respuesta es: '+respuesta);}`

Comment: Los parametros de la propiedad data deberian ser pasados en un objeto json para facilitar la legibilidad. Luego, en la consola estas viendo un undefined porque ajax es por definicion asincronico, la llamada no ha regresado a la hora en la que haces el console.log

Comment: Publícala como respuesta. Ha sido la solución. Muchas gracias hombre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El detalle está al pasar tus datos en el data, podrías intentar también así:

```
data: {codmaterial : codmaterial, descripcion : descripcionmaterial, unymed: unidadymedida, serializado: serializado, tipmat: tipomaterial, valor: valor, pertenencia: pertenencia},
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la forma general para hacer un llamada con ajax síncrona:

```
 $.ajax({
                data:  parametros, //datos a enviar en json (para mejor lectura)
                url:   'file.php', //archivo que recibe la llamada
                type:  'post', //método de envio
                async: false,
                success:  function (response) { //Una vez que la llamada fue realiada y procesada por el servidor, el resultado se recibe en 'response'
                        console.log(response);
                }
        });
```

Es en la función de success que debes mostrar el resultado de la llamada después de ser procesada.